# javascript replacing an object with an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object that looks like this (don't judge me).

```
{88:{1:{nTextID:179,bPublished:1}},
 89:{1:{nTextID:22,bPublished:1},
     2:{nTextID:22,bPublished:1}
    }
};
```

at some point in my lifecycle i build an object like this:

```
var category = {};
    category[categoryid] = {};
    category[categoryid][texttypeid] = {};
    category[categoryid][texttypeid].ntextid = $("#textid").val();
```

and pass it through to a function where I then find that category within my larger categories object and try to replace it:

```
var cattoreplace = 0;

for(item in category){
    $("#"+item).remove();
    cattoreplace = item;
    for(key in category[item]){
        category[item][key].ntextid = data.NTEXTID;
    }
}

for(item in jsonCategories){
    if(item == cattoreplace){
        delete jsonCategories[item];
        jsonCategories[item] = category;
    }
}
```

Now using the line `jsonCategories[item] = category;` ends me up with a structure like

```
{88:{88:{1:{nTextID:179,bPublished:1}}},
 89:{1:{nTextID:22,bPublished:1},
     2:{nTextID:22,bPublished:1}
    }
};
```

I want to keep the same structure as I have in my first codeblock example.

I'd like to know how to replace an item in my object with another object (without resorting to arrays, even if there are better merits... though if not possible do let me know).

Comment: _"which i don't want."_ - What is the output structure that you _do_ want?

Comment: Exactly the same as in the first code block

Comment: I think simply change `jsonCategories[item] = category` to `jsonCategories[item] = category[item]` will be ok.

Comment: you're certainly correct, stick it as an answer and you'll get the love.